# Updating a Textbox with current variable value

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, timer, textbox

I am trying to update a textbox with the current value of a variable (running in another thread) that I have:

```
myTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
myTimer.Interval = 1000;
myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(myTimerElapsed);
myTimer.Start();


private void myTimerElapsed(object sender, System.EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    myTextBox.Text = Convert.ToString(myThread.myValue);
}
```

which updates the Textbox every 1 sec. My question is if there is a better way of doing this without using a timer; for example an event that I can trigger whenever `myValue` changes to reflect the current value at all times?

Comment: That completely depends on how it changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using form.invoke(), you can update the textbox directly from your thread.

Form.Invoke() handles synchronizing the change when it can through the UI thread that the form us running on.

Declare the update delegate

```
public delegate void UpdateTextBoxDelegate(int value);
```

Start your thread in load_form

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(UpdateTextBoxThread));
thread.Start();
```

The thread method. Invoke is a method within the form class, so you may need to pass the instance of your form object to your thread class if you have your thread method in a different class.

```
public void UpdateTextBoxThread()
{
    for(int loop = 0; loop < 1000; loop++)
    {
        //Invoke the delegate within the UI thread context 
        Invoke(new UpdateTextBoxDelegate(InvokeUpdateTextBox), loop);
    }
}
```

The helper method that updates the textbox within the UI thread context

```
public void InvokeUpdateTextBox(int loop)
{
    textBox1.Text = loop.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing in my mind was making a hidden label and add the function of text_change

```
    private void lblMyValue_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          myTextBox.Text = lblMyValue.Text;
    }
```